# How to return a slice in Go and calling from C?

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to use `cgo` to use Go package in C code. Following is a piece of my code:

```
func LinearTransformToUInt8(frame []int64, winWidth int, winCenter int) []uint8 {
    var transformed []uint8
    // my cool code
    return transformed
}
```

However, when calling from C, it says

```
panic: runtime error: cgo result has Go pointer
```

I believe the problem is the returned `[]uint8` is a Go type, which should be replaced by a C type. However, I don't know how to achieve it. Please help!

Comment: Maybe you need to include more code so people know exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

> main.go

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "unsafe"
)
import (
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
}

//export phew
func phew() uintptr {
    res := make([]uint8, 2)
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        res[i] = uint8(i + 1)
    }
    hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&res))
    return hdr.Data
}
```

> main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include "libtemp.h"

int main(){
    uintptr_t resPtr = phew();
    uint8_t *res = (uint8_t*)resPtr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("%d\n", res[i]);
    }

    printf("Exiting gracefully\n");
}
```

You cannot pass a Go pointer which contains other Go Pointer, slice,string,channel,function, interface, map contain pointers.

So one cannot pass them around, rules to passing around pointers are documented [here](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers) and go's representation of basic types is documented [here](https://research.swtch.com/godata).

But some Go contributors were [saying](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27656), one shouldn't return a Go pointer to C code in the first place.